# Ho to convert date from mysql into gijgo datepicker

Tags: laravel-5, datepicker, date-format

In my I jQuery v3 / Bootstrap v4.1.2 application, I use gijgo.com/datepicker and I need to show some default value in datepicker
from “2019-04-09” in mysql database into “14 December, 2017”, as datepicker has options:

```
$('#check_in_datepicker').datepicker({    // bootstrap 4/ fontawesome compatible datepicker from https://gijgo.com/datepicker
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    format: 'dd mmmm, yyyy'
});
```

Which is the proper way for it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a decision in next definition

```
<date-picker
        v-model="this.hostelExtraDetailsArray.reception_hours_start"
        type="time"
        :time-picker-options="timePickerOptions"
        id="cbx_extra_details_reception_hours_start"
        :lang="'en'"
        :type="'time'"
        :format="'hh:mm'"
        :header="'HTRF'"
        :placeholder="'Select time from picker'"
></date-picker>
```

But recieving time from db field I convirted it with some dummy date :

```
   this.hostelExtraDetailsArray.reception_hours_start =
       this.stringIntoDatetime("2019-04-17 " + response.data.hostelExtraDetailsArray.reception_hours_start)
   ...
   stringIntoDatetime(string_datetime) {
       return moment.utc(string_datetime);
   }
```